# Want to position the background image in the middle

Tags: html, css, position, background-image, css-position

Hello on my login page I have a background image. Currently the image is centered but not centered the way I want it. I want it so the image is *always centered in the middle of the screen*. Curently, my image is centered but is positioned at the top of the page. The image need to be positioned in the middle of the screen, and kept centered.

```
login.html
 <body style="background-image: url({{MEDIA_URL}}/admin_media/img/admin/bigstock_Photo_Showing_Financial_Growth_1339836.jpg); background-position: 50% 50%; background-repeat:no-repeat;">
```

Answer (score 10):

may be you have write like this :

```
background-position: center center;
```

EDIT:

may be there problem with the `body` because it not takes screen entire `height` so if you want an image show in the center of the screen then write

```
html,body{height:100%;}
body{
    background:url(http://www.poster.net/van-gogh-vincent/van-gogh-vincent-sternennacht-2601013.jpg) no-repeat fixed center center;
}
```

check the example http://jsfiddle.net/sandeep/m2fZs/2/

Comment: `@sandeep` Nope, looks like it still does the same thing. (centered but positioned at the top of the page)

Comment: @Shehzad009: Would this maybe help you: http://css-tricks.com/3458-perfect-full-page-background-image/ ?

Comment: `@Andrej:` No I do not want my image to be streched. I just want this background image to be positioned in the center of the screen. Currently it is centerd at the top of the screen. I want it centered for both vertically and horizontally

Comment: @Shehzad009: check my latest example may be that's you want

Answer (score 1):

Instead of continuing to post comments, I thought it might be smarter to create a new answer.

Would something like [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/m2fZs/1/) work for you? (replace 'fixed' with 'scroll' , if you want the img to scroll up and down with the page)

Answer (score 0):

try it like this:

```
#element {
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-position:center;
}
```

this should work!